# Visual C++ 10 lowercases the __FILE__ macro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

The `__FILE__` preprocessor macro in Visual C++ 10 expands to the name of the source module, but in lowercase, e.g.

```
c:\path\to\my\file\somesource.cpp
```

when the file name is actually

```
SomeSource.cpp
```

Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: I'm seeing this in one C++ solution in Visual Studio 2017, and not in another one - on the same machine. I'm trying to work out what the difference is between the two projects. It gives me some hope that maybe there is a way to control it now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant, I [asked](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/630691/visual-c-10-lowercases-the-file-macro) the question on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) and got the following answer:

> Thanks for noting this. This behavior has existed for a while, at least back to VS 2008.
>   Changing the default behavior could potentially be a breaking change for other customers,
>   so we would prefer to keep the current behavior.
>   Since FOO.TXT is mostly the same as foo.txt for the file system,
>   hopefully using `__FILE__` with any comparison can just involve
>   a case-insensitive compare for your application.