# Correcting case of Visual C++ __FILE__ macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387629/visual-c-10-lowercases-the-file-macro) question.

We have a code generate tool (for cross platform C++ source files) and I need to correct the path returned by the ____FILE____ macro to have the correct case so that source files generated under Windows will still compile on case sensitive systems (eg. Linux and OSX).

I'm using Qt and have tried a few combinations of QFileInfo and QDir but they all seem to keep the lowercase path passed to it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Undefine it, and add your own `__FILE__` macro? Though it's nothing I recommend.

Comment: Why not just make sure the directory names are the correct case?

Comment: Mats, do you mean just enforce that all developers use only lowercase paths? This isn't just an internal tool, its going to be released and already has external users so that isn't a restriction I can enforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions, but I am not sure if it will work.

1. If you have not already tried this. Use QDir to search through the directories for the correct path.

   Say for instance that you are looking to include the file "C:/Programming/myProject/oneSource.cpp", then you do the following: Split the incoming path into "c:", "programming", "myproject", "onesource.cpp".

   Then you use QDir do search through "C:" for a folder that (ignoring case) matches "programming", but use the path returned from QDir. Rinse and repeat. This way you are not really passing any wrong paths to QT it will simply use the one it reads natively.
2. Try the exact same thing, but use a different library like [dirent](http://softagalleria.net/dirent.php) or even the native windows API.

Comment: Thanks Stain, using Windows native GetFullPathName() corrects the case so I'll just ifdef around the call and use this on Windows.

Answer (score -3):

You know the filename in your tool, so there's no reason at all to use the `__FILE__` macro. Just emit the correct file name as a string literal.