# Difference in Windows API output across debug and release configurations

Tags: c++

I'm using the following code for error logging in my code.

```
PathFindFileName(__FILE__);
```

But this call is returning different outputs(in terms of case of letters).
ie., in release it is giving the exact name, where as in debug it is returning all lower cases.

There is no harm due to this, but I'm just curious to know why there is a  difference in the output of same API.

Excuse me if this is an inappropriate question

Comment: Is the difference in the output of the API or already in the input? Did you verify that first?

Comment: Ok, "__FILE__" is the culprit. It's returning different values. Now tell me how this can happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ 10 lowercases the \_\_FILE\_\_ macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387629/visual-c-10-lowercases-the-file-macro)

Answer (score 2):

> Return value
>
> Type: PTSTR
>
> Returns a pointer to the address of the string if successful, or a
>   pointer to the beginning of the path otherwise.

`FindPathFileName` returns pointer to the file part substring of its argument. It does not allocate any memory to copy result string, its the same buffer with the same data. So if your debug code gets all lowercase result, it means, that lowercase string was passed to the function.

There could be no difference in Win32 API methods between debug and release versions, because you are calling the same methods from the same dynamic link libraries. If you are getting different results, it means only that function arguments are not the same.

PS: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17a395c7-b7dc-41a4-a19c-dda7afa3e063/why-file-returns-different-results-for-debug-and-release-vs-2012?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: But we are not passing any values to the function, explicitely. The function is fetching the value by itself, right?

Comment: @BrahmaprasadR: read up on the CPP. `__FILE__` is replaced even before the compilation, during preprocessing. It receives in string form (as a literal string, e.g. like `"C:\fle\bla\foo\bar.c"`) the name of the source file. So what is passed is that literal string. And that can differ depending on what the preprocessor inserts there.

Comment: Is there a way we can control this?

Comment: @BrahmaprasadR: no. Ask Microsoft and have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4387629 ... and don't forget to upvote that older Q&A ;)

Comment: Woww!!. That's convincing. Thanks a lot..@0xC0000022L